# doxc style List Paragraph

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a bunch of  docx documents that I am extracting text out of using python-docx. Extraction works out fine. However, I am having trouble getting hold of numbering for the paragraphs.

A word document could be:

1. Some Header: This is the first paragraph.
2. Second Header: This is the second paragraph.

I am iterating thru the paragraph like this:

```
print(paragraph.text)
print(paragraph.style)
print(paragraph._p.pPr.numPr.numId.val)
```

It prints the paragraph style as

```
_ParagraphStyle('List Paragraph') id: 2280433126816
```

which is good. it also prints the text correctly.

However, it always prints 1 for

```
print(paragraph._p.pPr.numPr.numId.val)
```

Comment: If I did convert the paragraph to "Heading 1" style, then it works fine.

Comment: If you stop at `print(paragraph._p.pPr.numPr)` do you get what you are looking for?

Comment: It looks like what you are trying to do is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52094242/is-there-any-way-to-read-docx-file-include-auto-numbering-using-python-docx)

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb - This is what I get <CT_NumPr '<w:numPr>' at 0x2319a195cc8>

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb - I tried your proposed solution too. Didn't work

Comment: The real answer is that what you are trying to do is not really supported as of now. If you inspect the xml for the file, you can figure out what the styling is for numbered lists, and then if you inspect any paragraph you can determine which style is being used, so combining those will get you the answer you want.

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb - Yeah, I think you are right. Using xml, it might be easier to achieve